# Links to Étienne Ghys's 2006 ICM Talk "Knots and Dynamics"

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, knot-theory

I recently came across [an ncat cafe post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/04/the_modular_flow_on_the_space.html) which discusses a 2006 talk by Étienne Ghys, which was recorded and put online [here](https://www.mathunion.org/Videos/ICM2006/muster.php?ghys2006) and [here](http://www.icm2006.org/video/).

Unfortunately, the recording seems to have vanished (at least, I cannot find it), and after looking through the source for these sites, it seems like the videos are missing because of the recent death of Adobe Flash.

After hearing this talk hyped as "the greatest math talk I’ve ever watched!" (see the top of the ncat cafe post), I started looking into Ghys's other talks and I've really been enjoying them. I've read [this article](http://www.josleys.com/articles/ams_article/Lorenz3.htm), which I believe follows a similar structure to the talk. There's also [this article](http://www.icm2006.org/proceedings/Vol_I/15.pdf), which I haven't read yet, but seems to be a more academic description of the same.

That said, I would still love to see the original talk if possible. Does anybody happen to know where it might be possible to do so? I remember reading somewhere that CDs of the event were distributed, so it's not impossible that somebody has put it online somewhere else.

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: [Found it.](https://www.mathunion.org/icm/icm-videos/icm-2006-videos-madrid-spain/icm-madrid-videos-24082006) The embed might be broken but you can find the .mp4 in the source

Comment: @DanielM !! Incredible, thank you ^_^.